# Default zoomout of gantt schedule on sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, gantt-chart

So my problem here is that i'm trying to get a default zoom level whenever someone enters the Schedule part in SharePoint, and i have this bit of code that is supposed to work 
``

```
jQuery.(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) WebPartWPQ2_JSGridController.ZoomOutGantt()
  }, 2000)
})

</script>
```

However when i try to use this code there is an error saying expected identifier, i have a lot of different similar codes and none of them works, i have also tried changing the jQuery. part to either $ or $. or just jQuery, and either the identifier problem remains or it says that it doesn't know what $ is.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a reference to jquery?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// By Cees Timmerman, 24oct12.
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("th[title='Title']").css({"width":"400px"})
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) WebPartWPQ2_JSGridController.ZoomOutGantt()
  }, 2000)
})</script>
```